# How to unhide mouse cursor on Nexus 7?

Tags: mouse, cursor, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I am using Synergy to control my Ubuntu on Nexus 7 using my desktop mouse and keyboard. However, the mouse cursor is displayed only if I connect my mouse via USB.

What service controls the visibility of the mouse cursor? How to make it visible manually?